# Using cookies with PHP and MySQL -- Good practice?

Tags: php, mysql, cookies

I have a site that stores registered user's site preferences in a MySQL database and am hoping to modify this so that non-registered users can use browser cookies to benefit from site configurations too.

Is there a common way to do this?  My thoughts were to create an additional database table with these fields:

```
id
unique_cookie_hash
site_preferences
```

Where the unique cookie hash is what's stored in the visitor's cookie and the site preferences is a JSON encoded string containing the guest user's settings.  So, for a user who is not logged in the site will check for a cookie.  If the cookie exists it will try and pull up preferences via the value stored in the cookie. If the cookie does not exist or a match was not found, the site will create one and assign it some default setting values.

As the guest makes changes the site will attempt to run an UPDATE query on their unique_cookie_hash.

I'm assuming this would work (and that it's how most sites do it?) but as it's a newer concept for me I was wondering if anyone knew of any good tutorials or 'got-yas' to watch out for with this method.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would work, just note that by serialising your options into a JSON string you can not select anything from them.

So if you wanted to know how many registered people like color scheme A, for example, you'd need to do all the code in PHP (at least in a non cumbersome way).

Comment: Agreed, it would be best to have the site_preferences stored in separate columns or a different table.  You wouldn't need to store the site_preferences on the client side at all and just store an identifier there and then look them up when the id is present in a cookie.

Comment: Cool, thanks Alex and Dylan!  I'm considering using individual columns but much of the settings are toggles to filter what information to display. (around 30) and something just sounds chaotically redundant about that many true/false fields.  And it would require a bit more query maintenance for adding future options.

Answer (score 0):

PHP has its own set of functions for managing sessions, and there are alternative (some might say better) libraries out there for session handling. It's a complex issue with unexpected security considerations, so I wouldn't try a homebrew solution without really researching it first.

Assuming you've looked into how to securely store session information, you can keep users' site preferences there, and when a user logs into their account, just copy their stored preferences to their session, which the site will actually act upon.

Answer (score -3):

It depends on the number of settings, but in general I wouldn't bother with database at all, but store them settings in a cookie.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Col. Shrapnel.  Yeah, I was wondering about that.  I think I immediately jumped toward looking for a solution involving the database because the user could only potentially alter the hashed key used for a lookup and not try and alter the setting values to some bizarre value of their own.  Though with proper security checks I'm sure this wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Not so good if they wanted their settings to be maintained over different browsers/computers.

Comment: @Col Well if their preferences are stored in their cookie, and then they login on another computer, their preferences won't be maintained. If they have a login, it might be nice to maintain the state of their preferences in the site's database.

Comment: @alex they don't have a login.

Comment: @Col The OP mentions registered and unregistered users. Sounds like they login to me.

Comment: @alex sure. "for a user who is **not logged in**" it says. Anyway it doesn't matter as unregistered user who logs in makes no sense.